# ExtFloodFill stuck with the Color white

Tags: c++, mfc

So i have been trying to repaint a bitmap programatically when user pressed a button with [`ExtFloodFill`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4a6334kf.aspx) with the code below

```
CDC* cdc = GetDlgItem(IDC_MAP_STATIC)->GetDC(); // Get the CStatic that contains the bitmap
cdc->SetDCBrushColor(COLOR_SKYBLUE);            // constant for #00EEEE
SetDCBrushColor((HDC)cdc, COLOR_SKYBLUE);       // Trying to change the cdc brush color
// Just for debugging, i have inspected it and the value is the same with the COLOR_SKYBLUE value           
COLORREF cr = cdc->GetDCBrushColor();
cdc->ExtFloodFill(x,cdc->GetCurrentPosition().y+y, RGB(0, 0, 0), FLOODFILLBORDER);
```

But everytime that i call ExtFloodFill the FloodFill will only fill the area with white color and as per the doc

> Fills an area of the display surface with the *current brush*.

I tried to change the current CDC brush color with the color skyblue. But it doesn't work at all.

IDC_MAP_STATIC is an usual CStatic object. I'm not using a subclassed CStatic for it.

So where did i do wrong that it caused the ExtFloodFill to keep Flood-filling my bitmap with white not skyblue?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, solved it right away with this snippet. I don't know why but when i set the brush color using SetDCBrushColor it doesn't change the selected brush. So with codes based from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145096(v=vs.85).aspx) article i tried to declare a new brush and select it before i tried to FloodFill it

```
CDC* cdc = GetDlgItem(IDC_MAP_STATIC)->GetDC();
CBrush cb(RGB(255, 0, 0)); //Make a new CBrush (Red)
cdc->SelectObject(&cb);    //Assign the CBrush to the CDC
cdc->ExtFloodFill(x,y, RGB(0, 0, 0), FLOODFILLBORDER);
DeleteObject(cb);
ReleaseDC(cdc);
```

Comment: You are either leaking a device context, or destroying it while there's still your brush selected into it. Neither one bodes well. Plus, an answer that doesn't explain what the issue was, and how it addressed that isn't entirely helpful.

Comment: You should just paint on your own window's DC, instead of doing what appears to be a hack.